# How to get the MySQL database connection resource from Kohana?

Tags: php, database-connection, kohana

I would like to get the default MySQL database connection in Kohana for use with a third-party library. How can I do that?

So far I have the following code:

```
$db = Database::instance('default');
$db->connect(); // After this, how can I retrieve the MySQL connection instance?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection is stored in a protected property in the Database class.

You can see this variable in the [Database](https://github.com/kohana/database/blob/3.1%2Fmaster/classes/kohana/database.php#L96) class and where it's being set in the [MySQL](https://github.com/kohana/database/blob/3.1%2Fmaster/classes/kohana/database/mysql.php#L59) class. If you wanted to have access to this variable then you can overload the Database class to provide a getter for it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know why do you need that, but Database::instance('default') each time returns a singleton instance, so you can use it anywhere in your code. 'default' can be considered as a connection name.

Comment: By "connection", I meant the link identifier that is returned by mysql_connect(). I guess it must be stored somewhere by Kohana and I would like to access it, to provide it to a third-party library.